# Excel-VBA: Do a calculation only if cells involve contain values

Tags: excel, average, vba

I have the code that nicely calculates the average I want. But now I want it to only run the calculation if the referenced cells contain values. I am totally stumped on how to feed conditions into my code.

```
Dim i%
Dim rng As Range
Dim last&
last = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To last
        Range("F" & i).FormulaR1C1 = _ 
            "=AVERAGE(R[-4]C[-2],R[-2]C[-2],RC[-2],R[2]C[-2],R[5]C[-2],)"
    Next i
End Sub
```

I tried working with AVERAGEIF, but I can't get it to work either. the range gives me a #Value in the range whenever I try to set it using the function wizard. So I have no idea how to make it work in VBA.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

*Edit - I only want the average line to appear in the cells, but I want to test the cells for values before doing the calculation. (Siddharth, thanks for your answer anyway!) To clarify:

```
Dim i%
Dim rng As Range
Dim last&
last = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To last
     'test for all cells having values here   
        Range("F" & i).FormulaR1C1 = _ 
            "=AVERAGE(R[-4]C[-2],R[-2]C[-2],RC[-2],R[2]C[-2],R[5]C[-2],)"
    Next i
End Sub
```

***Edit 2: To be more clear as to what I'm looking for, I want something like this:

```
Dim i%
Dim last&

last = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To last
    While Range("D" & i - 4).Value <> "" And Range("D" & i + 4).Value <> ""
        Range("F" & i).FormulaR1C1 = _ 
                 "AVERAGE(R[-4]C[-2],R[-2]C[-2],RC[-2],R[2]C[-2],R[5]C[-2]))"
    Wend
Next i
```

But my while statement is giving me trouble, as I keep getting an error when I reach that point in the code. I also have tried:

```
While Range("D" & i - 4 And "D" & i + 4).Value <> ""
```

Which gives me run time error 13: type mismatch.

Comment: You want the cell to stay blank (no value or formula) if the cells have no value?

Comment: Slightly confused with `R[-4]` when the value of i < 5

Comment: If you were to put the formula directly in say F2 in Excel, what would it be?

Comment: Tim-Yes, exactly. Siddharth - It loops around to the bottom of the column, which also contains no value.

Comment: I deleted  my post. Let me rework in it and post back

Comment: ok, if the cells are blank you don't want to calculate the average else you want to calculate? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: `While Range("C" & i - 4).Value <> "" And Range("C" & i + 4).Value <> ""` Did you by any chance mean Col D and for all 5 rows?

Comment: I think yo u need to take a moment and rethink because the average checks for i,i-2,i-4,i+2,i+5 cells.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then you need to check if the number of cells in a range equal the number of filled values. For example

```
Sub a()
    Dim i%
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim last&
    last = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To last
        Range("F" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(" & _
                     "Rows(R[-4]C[-2])+Rows(R[-2]C[-2])+Rows(RC[-2])+Rows(R[5]C[-2])<>" & _
                     "COUNTA(R[-4]C[-2],R[-2]C[-2],RC[-2],R[2]C[-2],R[5]C[-2],)-2,""Blank""," & _
                     "AVERAGE(R[-4]C[-2],R[-2]C[-2],RC[-2],R[2]C[-2],R[5]C[-2],))"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: But how can I do it without everything before the average showing up in the cell?

Comment: I didn't get your meaaning

Comment: I only want my equation to start as "=AVERAGE(..."

Comment: Why don't you try this then `=AVERAGE(IF(Rows(rng)<>COUNTA(rng)-2,rng,"Blank"))` You can take `rng` values from my code above